# digdag shell script tasks complete instantaneously

Tags: python, workflow, etl, pipeline, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm new to digdag. Below is an example workflow to illustrate my question:

_export:
sh:
shell: ["powershell.exe"]

_parallel: false

+step1:
sh>: py "C:/a.py"

+step2:
sh>: py "C:/b.py"

The second task runs right after the first task starts. However, I want the second task to wait for the first task to complete successfully.

I modified the first task a.py to just raise ValueError, but the second task still runs right after the first task starts.

This is not consistent with my understanding of the digdag documentation. But I dont know what goes wrong with my workflow. Could someone please advise?

Answer (score 0):

No. This can not be solved by redownloading.